# ggplot2: a script for stacked and a line chart

Tags: r, data-visualization

So far I was successful to get what I need using below mentioned script, but I'm sure my script is far from being perfect (if it is possible at all). So, I'd greatly appreciate your comments on how would it have been done differently in order to improve it.

```
p6_ch1 <- read.xlsx("BEO_charts.xlsx", sheet = 7, startRow = 2, colNames = T, rowNames = F, detectDates = T, skipEmptyCols = T, skipEmptyRows = T) 

p6_ch1$date <- as.Date(seq(as.Date("2009/1/1"), as.Date("2016/07/1")-1, by = "quarter"))
p6_ch1$date <- as.yearqtr(as.Date(p6_ch1$date, format = "Q%q %Y"))

p6_ch1_stack <- subset.data.frame (p6_ch1, select = c(1,3:5,7:9), p6_ch1$date >= "2013 Q1")
p6_ch1_line <- subset(p6_ch1, select = c(1,10), p6_ch1$date >= "2013 Q1")
p6_ch1_stack_melt <- melt(p6_ch1_stack, id.vars = "date", measure.vars = c(2:7)) 
p6_ch1_line_melt <- melt(p6_ch1_line, id.vars = "date")


p6.1 <- ggplot(data = p6_ch1_stack_melt, aes (x = date, y = value)) +
scale_x_yearqtr(breaks = seq(from = min(p6_ch1_stack$date, na.rm = T), to = max(p6_ch1_stack$date, na.rm = T), by=0.25), format="Q%q %Y", expand=c(.01,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-35,35), breaks = seq(-35,35,5)) + 
  xlab ("") +
  ylab ("") +

  geom_bar(data = p6_ch1_stack_melt, 
        aes(
          group = variable,
          fill=variable),
          stat = 'identity') +

  scale_fill_manual(
    guide = "legend", 
    name = NULL, 
    breaks= c(
      "tax_inc",
      "ved_inc",
      "oth_inc",
      "current_exp",
      "debt_service",
      "capex"), 
    labels= c(
      "Налоговые доходы*", 
      "Доходы от ВЭД", 
      "Прочие доходы", 
      "Текущие расходы**", 
      "Обслуживание госдолга", 
      "Капитальные расходы"),
    values = c(
      "#88CCEE", 
      "#44AA99", 
      "#117733", 
      "#DDCC77", 
      "#CC6677", 
      "#AA4499"))

p6.1 <- p6.1 + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0),colour="#ABABAB")
p6.1 <- p6.1 + 
  geom_line(data = p6_ch1_line_melt, aes(x = date, y = value, colour = variable), size = 1) + 
  geom_point(data = p6_ch1_line_melt, aes(x = date, y = value, colour = variable), size = 1) +

  scale_colour_manual(
    guide = "legend", 
    name = NULL, 
    breaks = c("balance"), 
    labels = c("Сальдо"), 
    values = c("#332288", "#332288")) +

    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .5, size = 5, colour = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 5, colour = "black"),
        #panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(colour = "#EDEDED", linetype = 2),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "#EDEDED", linetype = 2, size = .3),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour = "#EDEDED"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_line(colour="#ABABAB"), 
        axis.ticks.length = unit(0,"cm"),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.spacing.x = unit(-.2,"cm"),
        legend.key = element_blank(),
        legend.key.height = unit(.3, "cm"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 5),
        legend.box.margin = unit (c(-9,1,1,1), "mm"),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
        plot.margin = unit (c(1,1,0,-4), "mm"))  

p6.1

CairoPDF("plot6.1.pdf", width=5.23622, height=2.83465)
plot(p6.1)
dev.off()
```

The script gives me a chart I need:

[image]